# Threshold for R DPLYR

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a table like so:

```
Task_ID |  Home_Id  |  Pet_Id  |  
----------------------------------
 10000    | 1203010   | 123      | 
 1010     | 3402034   | 120      | 
 43240    | 1239502   | 101      | 
 43240    | 1230102   | 101      | 
 43240    | 1234020   | 98       | 
 10000    | 1203010   | 123      |
 10000    | 1203010   | 123      |
```

For each Task, I want to get the list of Pets that appear in at least 50% of the Homes
For example, if there were 10 rows with task id 1000, and pet_id appeared in 5/10 of the home_ids within task 10000, I would want to flag it.

For my end result I want to get the Pet_Ids for each Task_Id that appear in 50% of homes.

Expected Output:

```
Task_ID |  Pet_Id  |  
--------------------
 10000  |123       | 
 1010   |120       |
 432420 |101       |
```

How can I do this in R?

I'm thinking I can group by the InspectionTaskName and do some sort of summarisation? Not sure how I can start.

Comment: updated. does this make more sense?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option with `base R` using `table` and `stack`.  The logic is to `split` the data columns except the 'Task_ID' by 'Task_ID', loop over the `list` (`split` output) with `lapply`, get the `table` of the dataset (assuming there are only two columns - 'Home_Id', 'Pet_Id'), find the proportion of logical matrix with `colMeans`, extract the `names` of those which have proportion greater than 0.5 and `stack` it to a two column data.frame

```
stack(lapply(split(df1[-1], df1$Task_ID),
     function(x) names(which(colMeans(table(x) > 0) > 0.5))))[2:1]
#    ind values
#1  1010    120
#2 10000    123
#3 43240    101
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`, after grouping by 'Task_ID', 'Pet_Id', get the number of distinct elements of 'Home_Id' and `filter` by the proportion

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(Task_ID, Pet_Id)  %>% 
   dplyr::summarise(n = n_distinct(Home_Id)) %>%
   filter( n/sum(n) > 0.5) %>%
   select(-n)
# A tibble: 3 x 2
# Groups:   Task_ID [3]
#  Task_ID Pet_Id
#    <int>  <int>
#1    1010    120
#2   10000    123
#3   43240    101
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Task_ID = c(10000L, 1010L, 43240L, 43240L, 43240L, 
10000L, 10000L), Home_Id = c(1203010L, 3402034L, 1239502L, 1230102L, 
1234020L, 1203010L, 1203010L), Pet_Id = c(123L, 120L, 101L, 101L, 
98L, 123L, 123L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L
))
```

Comment: I like your dplyr version that you had. You deleted it but the `n` you had in the summarise basically gave me my expected numerator for the percentage. I just need the denominator which is the total number of home_ids

Comment: n/sum(n) will always give me 1

Comment: @Eisen Any chance you loaded `plyr` along with `dplyr` which results in masking of `summarise` or `mutate`

Comment: @Eisen try with `dplyr::summarise(n = n_distinct(Home_Id))` explicitly

Comment: That doesn't work. When you group by Task_Id and Pet_Id the n that you have in your summarise will give me the number of times the paragraph id appears in each home_id. I need to divide that by the total number of home_ids to get the rate which i can filter off of

Comment: @Eisen. The `summarise` step 'n' is based on grouping by 'Task_ID', and 'Pet_Id', after the `summarise`, one group is lost i.e. Pet_Id by default option, now it is only grouping by 'Task_ID', thus the `sum(n)` is sum of n values per 'Task_ID'

Comment: @Eisen can you post a better example as I am getting the same output in base R and tidyverse for this one